# No resource identifier found for attribute 'backgroundTint' in package 'android'

Tags: android, eclipse, attributes, styles

I found some view xml attributes such as `backgroundTint`, `backgroundTintMode`.
But when I use it as view attribute difinition, Eclipse shows an error for:

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'backgroundTint' in package 'android'
```

And when I use it as style definition, Eclipse shows error for:

```
 No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:backgroundTint'
```

I want to use those attributs normally in Eclipse, can someone help me?

Comment: Can you show us your XML? And what's your SDK version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[backgroundTint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)) and [backgroundTintMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundTintMode(android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode)) are only available in API level 21+ (Lollipop)

Comment: Thanks.I think that's because I didn't instanll Android SDK Platform API level 21.