# Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView at View.java

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

Here is a bug, reported by `Crashlytics` with my app.
I have tried almost everything to fix it without luck.
This app use `ActionBar` with `spinner`, no exotic stuff.
It seems to happen on `Samsung devices with Lollipop` and more, and it's not quite frequent
There is the logcat from Samsung device on 5.1.1.

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:4262)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:4334)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2227)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4089)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3259)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:4262)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:4334)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2227)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4089)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3259)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:774)
   at android.view.View.(View.java:4009)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:513)
   at com.android.internal.widget.AbsActionBarView.(AbsActionBarView.java:74)
   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.(ActionBarContextView.java:103)
   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.(ActionBarContextView.java:98)
   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.(ActionBarContextView.java:94)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:4262)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:4334)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2227)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4089)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3259)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Thanks for any helpfull ideas !

Comment: Did you try look for `?attr/` attributes in your xml ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595187/android-xml-runtimeexception-failed-to-resolve-attribute-at-index-6 )? Maybe you can post some of the problematic code/xml.

Comment: Yes, already done.
The problem is I can't figure out which part is problematic :s

Comment: I think this was caused by Samsung Touchwiz animations, which interrupt inflating views. Observe if mistakes would happen again